# П. І. Б., П.І.Б. чи ПІБ?

Tags: орфографія, разом-дефіс-окремо, скорочення

Недавно було питання про те, як правильно П.І.Б. чи П.І.П. Це мене наштовхнуло на питання про те, ***як тоді саму абревіатуру на скорочення прізвища, ім’я та по батькові слід записувати,*** **без крапок і пробілів, з крапками і з пробілами чи лише з крапками**?

У [Словнику скорочень української мови](http://www.ukrskor.info/?text=%D0%9F%D0%86%D0%91) є без пробілів і крапок;

На сайті [Правова консультація](https://www.pravoconsult.com.ua/chomu-vi-shhe-dosi-ne-zminili-svoye-im-ya/) є з крапками, але без пробілів;

А [тут](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=t85zej2iVz8C&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%D0%9F.+%D0%86.+%D0%91.&source=bl&ots=-DXRVyxcJA&sig=y_FXBV6RFNMheTDYTLrGpVyBFbQ&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWt6iP9rLaAhVI8ywKHS_oB3UQ6AEIWTAJ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F.%20%D0%86.%20%D0%91.&f=false) і з крапками, і з пробілами.

То як правильно записувати у друкованих текстах?

Comment: Скажу відразу, що з точки зору правопису варіант з крапками без пробілів і варіант з крапками з пробілами нічим не відрізняються (довжина пробілів — то вже нюанси оформлення, а не правопису). Але зазвичай у ретельно оформлених текстах після крапок пробіли ставлять (не ставлять їх часто лише для того, щоб запобігти розриву рядка в цьому місці — але для цього насправді є нерозривний пробіл). А от чи потрібні крапки — то вже питання.

Comment: Друзі, там у нас є теґ [tag:разом-дефіс-окремо], він не дуже вдалий для цього запитання, тому прошу висловитися стосовно того, як краще переробити.

Comment: а мені подобається! правда, щось не здогадалася відразу, чому посередині пише "дефіс"))) Але от чи саме до цього питання теґ личить, то щось вагаюся...

Comment: @ОксанкаСтрус, той тег створено, щоб обʼєднати усі запитання подібного виду. В усіх попередніх запитаннях ішлося про складні іменники чи прислівники, і там як раз питання постає саме так: писати разом або через дефіс або через пробіл. З одного боку, перейменовувати не хочеться (втрачаючи «дефіс»), а з іншого боку, новий тег створювати для пари «разом-окремо» — теж не comme il faut. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ця абревіатура підпадає під другий пункт [§ 39](http://pravopys.net/sections/39/) Українського правопису як складноскорочена ініціальна абревіатура, утворена від загального імені. Ця стаття не передбачає написання абревіатур з крапками. До того ж в [одному](https://www.pravoconsult.com.ua/chomu-vi-shhe-dosi-ne-zminili-svoye-im-ya/) з ваших джерел пишуть "ПІБ" також:

> “Кожен громадянин України може змінити власне прізвище, ім’я і по батькові (ПІБ)”

Отже, "ПІБ" правильно писати **разом і без крапок**.